# Any open source Ajax Scheduler for jquery/asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Is there any open source Ajax Scheduler (with week and month view) for jquery or asp.net? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by scheduler? Is it not just a calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following links:

- http://www.socialmedian.com/story/6694170/jquery-week-calendar-the-scheduler (**dead**)
- http://www.scriptcalendar.com/scrptcal/example.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You must try this jquery one: http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/

It's free and open source.

wdCalendar is a javascript event calendar. Simply said, this jquery plugin is a Google calendar clone, which is similar to desktop calendar applications such as Microsoft Outlook or iCal on Mac OS X.

It’s easy for users to view, add, and drag-and-drop events from one date to another. It supports view modes such as daily, weekly, monthly. It is very powerful yet easy to use & integrate with php, asp.net, jsp and RoR.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying for a license, you could check out the Ext Scheduler which has a pretty good feature set:

http://ext-scheduler.com

Comment: Your affiliation to the company that sells Ext Scheduler should be disclosed in your answer.

Comment: Clearly. And I'm still looking for the OpenSource part of the product.